# How to pass a variable from controller to model in codeigniter?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Controller:

```
$this->data['students'] = $this->student_m->get_order_by_student_sattendance($id);
```

Model:

```
function get_order_by_student_sattendance($val) {
    $this->db->select()->from(student)->where('FIND_IN_SET($val, classesID)');
        $query = $this->db->get();
        return $query->result();
}
```

Hello, i just pass a variable $id to model as $val. But the result is Unknown column '$val' in 'where clause'
SELECT * FROM `student` WHERE FIND_IN_SET($val, classesID). I think passing parameter is incorrect. Kindly suggest me the right code.

Thanks in advance

Comment: `from(student)` looks suspicious to me. Shouldn't it be `from('student')`?

Comment: did you echo $val variable in side function  ? if you got $val inside the function then your value is passing to model successfully. but your query part may wrong.

Comment: Yes echo working. when echo 6 displayed. So i use this code $this->db->select()->from(student)->where('FIND_IN_SET(6, classesID)'); its working fine. but when i declare variable as $val its not working. Iam confused

Answer (score 4):

if your are using single quote ('), you must use concatenation

```
->where('FIND_IN_SET(' . $val . ', classesID)');
```

OR use double qoute (")

```
->where("FIND_IN_SET($val, classesID)");
```

Comment: Thank you so much this code working for me >where('FIND_IN_SET(' . $val . ', classesID)'); Thanks again

Answer (score -1):

try this..change **$id** to **$val**

$this->data['students'] = $this->student_m->get_order_by_student_sattendance($val);

Comment: Apparently, $id is given and get_order_by_student_sattendance takes $val. Unknown column '$val' in 'where clause' hints that using $val as string, not as a variable is the problem.